# Do I have to set the proper device when 'cudaMemcpy' from device to host?

Tags: cuda

ptr is malloced when set device to 1, and before copying 'ptr' to 'host_ptr' from device to host, do I have to set device to 1 again?

```
cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaMalloc(ptr, size);

//do something here
...

cudaSetDevice(0);

//do something here
...
//cudaSetDevice(1); #My qustion: is this line needed?

cudaMemcpy(host_ptr, ptr, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: @Shadow I've tested both, all worked. So I am confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on a platform which supports [unified virtual addressing](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space), then all allocations on all devices are mapped into a single address space, and the API is aware of which physical device a given address resides. As a result, it would appear that the  `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` works correctly because of this pointer resolution without the need to explicitly select a device.

> do I have to set device to 1 again?

Theoretically, yes you should. You are implicitly relying on something which isn't necessarily supported on all platforms (yet). Alternatively, you should embrace unified memory completely, use `cudaMemcpyDefault` and let the API take care of the details. But embracing unified memory implies that your code won't work on some systems. It really depends what your goal is with the code you are writing.